# How to track change using Jquery if any field is being changed using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to use Jquery if any field is being changed using javascript?

I have hidden field whose value is being changed as per change of other field using javascript.

Now I want jquery event function which can track this change of hidden field and do the needful.

I tried with this :

```
jQuery("#bannersize").change(function()
```

but it didnt worked for me as i wanted.

How can i do it?

Comment: You have to explicitly trigger the "change" event from your code that changes the field value.  No events are automatically generated (by all browsers) when a field value is changed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following should trigger a "change" event.  Call this code after you change your hidden field value:

```
$('#bannersize').trigger('change');
```

Comment: +1 Do u mean to place in below html code or above the jQuery("#bannersize").change(function()

Comment: I mean place it wherever you are changing your hidden field value (I'm assuming you have some javascript which changes your hidden field value?)